# Can't create an Import with FuelSDK-Ruby

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

When I try to create an Import Definition with the Ruby Fuel-SDK I get the following error message:

"Select the appropriate destination for a Destination Type of Data Extension"

The properties that I'm using to create the Import are:

{"Name"=>"Table", "CustomerKey"=>"...", "Description"=>"Created with Ruby SDK", "AllowErrors"=>"true", "DestinationObject"=>{"ObjectID"=>"..."}, "FieldMappingType"=>"InferFromColumnHeadings", "FileSpec"=>"Table.csv", "FileType"=>"CSV", "RetrieveFileTransferLocation"=>{"CustomerKey"=>"..."}, "Notification"=>{"ResponseType"=>"email", "ResponseAddress"=>"email@email.com"}, "UpdateType"=>"Overwrite"}

Anyone has had a similar problem?

Edit:

When I run the specified code I get:

[Code log](https://gist.github.com/txominpelu/9c019dcffa9260a3c69c)

Comment: That can happen if the Savon version isn't 2.2.0.  The SDK doesn't support newer versions at this time.

Comment: Thanks @mac , I've checked and the version of Savon that is installed locally is the 2.2.0

Comment: If I run that I get:

Comment: I've updated the question with the log that I get when I run the code you've just given me.

Comment: When I click the link for the code log, it appears blank, is that what you are seeing?

Comment: Ah nope, sorry. I had misspelled the link. I've corrected it now.

Comment: That looks correct.  If you turn on Debug mode for the SDK, what is the output?  Information for that is in the readme: https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-Ruby

Comment: You can find the log in a second file that I've added to the same link.

Comment: For the DestinationObject->ObjectID, are you sure that exists in the account?  Keep in mind the ObjectID is a system generated value, not the same as CustomerKey that is visible in the UI.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the problem. It works now that I'm using the CustomerKey ,

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, please mark the answer as approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the output if you run the following in your environment:

```
require 'savon'
p Gem.loaded_specs["savon"].version
```

If that shows the gem is 2.2.0 then that isn't the issue. Sometimes the gem version being used is confusing so this is the best way to check.

I believe the real answer to this question is that the wrong identifier was used. The ObjectID being specified for the Data Extension is a system generated GUID which is not the same as the CustomerKey/ExternalKey which is the unique identifier that can be set at the time the data extension is created.  It is called CustomerKey in the API and External Key if looking in the UI but the value is the same.

It gets confusing because if a value is not provided for CustomerKey/ExternalKey then the system generates a GUID for this field but it is not the same as the GUID generated for the ObjectID.  The ObjectID can be looked up for a data extension by performing a retrieve through the API or the code can be updated to use CustomerKey instead to resolve this issue.